# How to make anonymous looking not anonymous?

Tags: privacy, tor

Is it possible to avoid detecting yourself as user of anonymous proxy, while browsing using Tor or I2P?

UPD The problem is that some sites just block users from anonymous proxies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are places that list all TOR exit nodes. So whatever is checking for your "anonymous proxy" status, is checking against that list. There's no way to bypass that.
I imagine there's something similar with I2P.

Comment: Doesn't this make all idea of Tor defective by design? If a totalitarian government wants to block Tor, it can do this without too much troubles.

Comment: If that gov't wants to block TOR nodes from accessing stuff THEY control, they can. But they can't see INSIDE of TOR traffic, so they can't block a decedent from accessing TOR exit nodes.

Comment: They can't block access to/from exit nodes by IP address?

Comment: No, because routing to exit nodes happens inside of TOR. You should really read up https://www.torproject.org/about/overview. It explains how TOR works. :)

Comment: I don't see any explanation about exit nodes there.

Comment: It has explanation of how encrypted traffic goes from node to node. You don't establish direct connections to exit nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I know of to make it pretty. In theory if you just need to do this every once in a while and you don't care about the location you could use an browser proxy. Those tend to identify themselves with their actual location. This should change you popups to "I'm a single in Bolivia and I'm ready to mingle!". Have fun.

Comment: But I don't want to dispose my true identity :) The problem is that some sites just block users from anonymous proxies, what basically makes Tor useless.

Comment: A VPN would work. And those proxies don't exactly care. A majority of them don't keep and record of your existence.